# How to uncheck checkbox if other checked using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried the below code to uncheck the 1st checkbox if any one of the below are checked. But not able to revert back to the initial stage i.e. if nothing is selected the first checkbox will checked.

```js
$('ol input').on('click', function() {
  if(this.checked){  
    $('#all').prop('checked', false);
  }else{
    $('#all').prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

```css
ol li{list-style:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="all" checked>All
  <ol>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox">1
      <input type="checkbox">2
      <input type="checkbox">3
      <input type="checkbox">4
      <input type="checkbox">5
    <li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your current else statement, try `else if ($('ol input:checked').length == 0)`

```js
$('ol input').on('click', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('#all').prop('checked', false);
  } else if ($('ol input:checked').length == 0) {
    $('#all').prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

```css
ol li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="all" checked>All
  <ol>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox">1
      <input type="checkbox">2
      <input type="checkbox">3
      <input type="checkbox">4
      <input type="checkbox">5
      <li>
  </ol>
</div>
```